# Как исправить артефакты отображения IDE QTCreator?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, отладка, qtcreator

[image: Пример глюков]

После обновления Linux Ubuntu версии 20.04 LTS до 22.04 LTS стали появляться постоянные глюки отображения графического интерфейса QTCreator(версия 6.0.2). То черный экран на половину IDE, то ещё что. Лечится выделением текста, изменением размера окна и тд, и худо бедно продолжать разработку можно. Однако безумно раздражает. В связи с чем я просто поменял IDE, но очень хочется вылечить данные глюки. Как думаете, как это можно было бы исправить(переустановка ubuntu не помогла, как и переустановка qtcreator)?

Comment: Может, графика? Поставить проприетарные дрова?

Comment: В других IDE такого не наблюдается. В свою очередь для Ububntu использую VMWare Player.

Comment: Я не уверен, но мне все же думается, что дело в графике. Тем более, виртуалка. На Linux хосте такого не наблюдал, на гостевой не пробовал. Могу только предложить попробовать пробросить видео карту в виртуалку.

Comment: Хорошо. Может быть настройки графики у системы сбились?

Comment: Может. После обновлений дистра вообще стоит прошерстить настройки. И не только графики.

Comment: К тому же графический интерфейс Qt может зависеть от библиотек OpenGL/GLU (mesa). А другие Ваши IDE, в которых проблем нет, могут их не использовать.